# How can I accurately flatten a surface?

Tags: sculpting

[image]

I want to flatten some places of a sculpted plane back to the original level, but flatten and smooth don´t work the way I want them to. The grease pencil marks the areas where the sculpt should be flat. What can I do?

Comment: Recalculate normals of the mesh first (Ctrl+N with all selected, Edit mode), that's likely the reason for brushes not working as expected. Note that sculpting brushes take into account normals orientation, if orientation is inside brush effect will be inverted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to flatten faces the surface, select all the faces that you want to flatten and scale 0 to the axis you want it to be flat to. I'm assuming you want to flatten it to the Z axis. In order to do this, press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, this was pretty useful. I had to clean up the file quite manually, but I used this shortcuts a few times.

Answer (score 0):

This also helps with strokes not aligning with grease pencil color layers when trying to render with the camera position in the 2.8 update.

You have to reduce the strokes and color of everything on the depth axis to 0. It might be your Z or Y depending how you drew your layer. You get some warped results if when you're using anything beyond that. This flattens your image so it can render correctly your strokes and color in whatever position you want in the 3D space as a 2D object.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't it be best to just set up a custom orientation then scale to zero on the axis you want? You could then reuse it whenever you want.

Comment: Please tell the user *how* to set up a custom orientation, otherwise this might be better suited as a comment.

Comment: Could you explain how to achieve that @Ray Mairlot plz? I want to clean up my file further. Is it possible to make a sculpt brush flatten to a certain level/ level0 so there are still levels in between? When i use S Z 0 enter, it flattens very abrubtly.